# Setting test items in CodeIgniter Unit Test not effecting report output

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm running CodeIgniter 2.0 and I have a test controller setup with this code in the index function. It seems like no matter what I put in the "set_test_items" variable, the report never changes. It always show all of the possible information regarding the test. I feel like I must be missing something blatantly obvious here. What am I missing?

```
    $this->unit->set_test_items(array('test_name', 'result'));

    $this->_test_user_lib();
    $this->_test_user_model();

    echo $this->unit->report();
```

Also, I just tried to var_dump() on the visible items when the report is generated and the array only contains the two things I passed in, so it is being set correctly.

Comment: think you need to post more information..views, your test functions. try the whole controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set_test_items()` affects only the `run()` methods, not `report()`. The following code will show only the items you specified in `set_test_items()`:

```
echo $this->unit->run(1 + 1, 2, 'One plus one');
```

But the following will show all items:

```
echo $this->unit->report();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the **Unit_class** library to fix the run method.

Here is an example using the array helper "elements" to keep only the elements in >_test_items_visible.

**Note:** This way, you have to set the visible items **BEFORE** run the tests.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Unit_test extends CI_Unit_test 
{
  /**
   * Llamamos al constructor del padre 
   *
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
  }


  /**
   * Reemplazamos la función RUN
   */
  function run($test, $expected = TRUE, $test_name = 'undefined', $notes = '')
  {
    // Sacamos la versión
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->helper('array');


    if ($this->active == FALSE)
    {
      return FALSE;
    }

    if (in_array($expected, array('is_object', 'is_string', 'is_bool', 'is_true', 'is_false', 'is_int', 'is_numeric', 'is_float', 'is_double', 'is_array', 'is_null'), TRUE))
    {
      $expected = str_replace('is_float', 'is_double', $expected);
      $result = ($expected($test)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
      $extype = str_replace(array('true', 'false'), 'bool', str_replace('is_', '', $expected));
    }
    else
    {
      if ($this->strict == TRUE)
        $result = ($test === $expected) ? TRUE : FALSE;
      else
        $result = ($test == $expected) ? TRUE : FALSE;

      $extype = gettype($expected);
    }

    $back = $this->_backtrace();


    // Only visible elements
    $report[] = elements
    (
      $this->_test_items_visible, array 
      (
        'test_name'     => $test_name,
        'test_datatype' => gettype($test),
        'res_datatype'  => $extype,
        'result'        => ($result === TRUE) ? 'passed' : 'failed',
        'file'          => $back['file'],
        'line'          => $back['line'],
        'notes'         => $notes
      )
    ) ;

    $this->results[] = $report;

    return($this->report($this->result($report)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the report() method

```
echo $this->unit->report();
```

you can run the result() method:

```
echo $this->unit->result();
```

This will give you just the items you have selected but in a raw data format (ie. an associative array) this is probably better because the format of the report isn't that great. You can then load them into a view and format them how you want:

```
$data['test_results'] = $this->unit->result();
$data['title'] = 'Pricing Test';
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('tests/index', $data);
```